# Combining imputations of generalized linear model regression coefficients - same as linear multiple regression?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, multiple-imputation, mice

I'm doing some imputation with the MICE package. The outcome variables I am using are zero-inflated, and in the absence of imputation, I would analyze them with a zero-inflated negative binomial regression (ZINB). I would like to do the same with the imputed data; however, I have to manually combine parameters since MICE or its add-ons (as far as I know), do not generate estimates for ZINB.

My question is whether Rubin's Rule for combining regression parameters (which, to my knowledge, is simply the mean) would apply to regression parameters for ZINB. I believe that regular linear multiple regression parameters can be combined in such a way because they are approximately normally distributed. Do regression parameters for ZINB (and for that matter, Poisson and logistic regression) approximate a normal distribution in the same way? In other words, is the Rubin's Rule for combining ZINB and other generalized linear regression parameters the same as combining regression parameters from a linear multiple regression?

Thank you!

Comment: Are these parameters estimated using MLE? If so they should in general have an asymptotic normal distribution and Rubin's rules should be valid.

Comment: If the zero in your data are real and not missing (MCAR ideally) it would be wrong to impute them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual estimates for the zero-inflated negative binomial model will be maximum likelihood estimates (see details [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/zinb/)). Since maximum likelihood estimates are asymptotically normal, you could justify using Rubin's combining rules if you believe that your application has enough data such that asymptotic normality is approximately a correct description of the sampling distribution of your parameter estimates.